# Getting Pricebook entry Error

Tags: pricebook, pricebookentry

Hello I want to automatically add a secondary product when a user adds a product to an Opportunity. I have a trigger that feeds the lineitem to a class.
My class then looks for the product but continually returns error of has no rows for assignment.

```
List <opportunityLineItem> AddRevProducts = new List <opportunityLineItem>();

        for(opportunityLineItem ELI:OLIs){
            system.debug('ELIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIIII'+ELI);
            OpportunityLineItem AddProd= new OpportunityLineItem();
            AddProd.OpportunityId=ELI.OpportunityId;
            AddProd.Quantity=1;
            AddProd.UnitPrice=eli.Product_Hosting_Revenue__c;
            AddProd.PricebookEntryId=[select id from Pricebookentry 
                                         where isactive=true
                                         and ProductCode = 'Hosting Revenue'
                                         and Pricebook2Id =: eli.Opportunity.pricebook2id 
                                         LIMIT 1].id;
            AddRevProducts.add(AddProd);
        }
database.insert(AddRevProducts);
(further processing)
```

The query returns no rows for assignment. But there is an active product in the pricebook! and the below query returns the id of it!

```
    select id from Pricebookentry     where isactive=true
                                             and ProductCode = 'Hosting Revenue'
                                             and Pricebook2Id = 
'(pricebook2id taken from Opportunity in question)'
```

Please help, thanks!

Comment: Problems like this are hard to troubleshoot over the internet because we don't have access to your org to look at things like security settings or the various data points on the records in question. My advice is to use system debug statements throughout the whole thing to check all your data points are as you expect. Another thought maybe that you're getting the error in a test class (since you didn't specify one way or the other) in which case you may not have made all of the records necessary during your setup.

Comment: Updating my debug I see the variable eli.Opportunity.pricebook2i is null-

Comment: Well, there's your problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying the Pricebook2Id of the Opportunity was adding queries so I made a formula field on the Opportunity Product to use for easier reference for this and other code.
So

```
 and Pricebook2Id =: eli.Opportunity.pricebook2id
```

becomes

```
 and Pricebook2Id =: eli.PBid__c
```

Comment: That makes sense and I'm kind of frustrated that I didn't catch it because I've run into that problem before. The trigger won't have the value of a field on a related object unless you query for it. Using a formula field should solve that with 1 fewer query.